# How can I get generics to work in Python.NET with CPython

Tags: python, .net, clr, ironpython, python.net

How can I get generics to work in Python.NET with CPython. I get an error when using the subscript syntax from [Python.NET Using Generics](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#generics)

```
TypeError: unsubscriptable object
```

With Python 2.7.11 + pythonnet==2.1.0.dev1

```
>python.exe
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import clr
>>> from System import EventHandler
>>> from System import EventArgs
>>> EventHandler[EventArgs]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsubscriptable object
```

I've also tried pythonnet==2.0.0 and building form github ca15fe8 with ReleaseWin x86 and got the same error.

With IronPython-2.7.5:

```
>ipy.exe
IronPython 2.7.5 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.0 (32-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import clr
>>> from System import EventHandler
>>> from System import EventArgs
>>> EventHandler[EventArgs]
<type 'EventHandler[EventArgs]'>
```

Comment: Your ironpython example is not complete, this question seems outdated from the one you asked on github

Comment: @denfromufa I've updated my examples.

With IronPython the subscript syntax instantiates the EventHandler as expected but with CPython+Python.NET it returns an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the generic class object explicitly:

```
EventHandler = getattr(System, 'EventHandler`1')
```

The number indicates the number of generic arguments.

Comment: in pythonnet 2.1 you fixed this issue! please edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work because there are both generic and non-generic versions of the `EventHandler` class that exist in the `System` namespace. The name is overloaded.  You need to indicate that you want the generic version.

I'm not sure how exactly Python.NET handles overloaded classes/functions but it seems like it has an `Overloads` property.  <strike>Try something like this and see how that goes:</strike>

```
EventHandler_EventArgs = EventHandler.Overloads[EventArgs]
```

(this doesn't work)

It doesn't seem like Python.NET has ways to resolve the overloaded class name, each overload is treated as separate distinct types (using their clr names).  It doesn't do the same thing as IronPython and lump them into a single containing type.

In this particular case, the `EventArgs` name corresponds to the non-generic `EventArgs` type.  You'll need to get the appropriate type directly from the System module as filmor illustrates.

Comment: I get a "TypeError: No match found for constructor signature" when I try that.

Comment: Hmm, I guess the `Overloads` property only applies to methods (in this case, constructors).  It would be a shame if Python.net didn't offer a way to do this natively.