# Pythonnet delegate method with generics not being called

Tags: c#, python, generics, delegates, python.net

I'm using a Python script with Pythonnet to drive a C# library. This library fires delegate methods on certain events. I'm registering the delegate method but it isn't being called.

The method in question is defined as `event EventHandler<EventArgs> SystemInformationUpdated`

The funny thing is that another method with a custom class return value IS being called, defined as `event EventHandler<PeripheralDiscoveredEventArgs> PeripheralDiscovered`

When I run this code with IronPython everything works fine, so I think it's a PythonNET issue. My code is like this:

```python
from System import EventHandler, EventArgs

(...)

dc = EventHandler[PeripheralDiscoveredEventArgs](centralOnPeripheralDiscovered_callback)
central.PeripheralDiscovered += dc

iuc = EventHandler[EventArgs](systemInformationUpdated_callback)
central.SystemInformationUpdated += iuc
```

The `systemInformationUpdated_callback` is **NOT** being executed while the `centralOnPeripheralDiscovered_callback` function is being called.

I also tried the following code:

```python
from System import EventArgs

(...)

EventHandler = getattr(System, 'EventHandler`1')
dc = EventHandler[PeripheralDiscoveredEventArgs](centralOnPeripheralDiscovered_callback)
central.PeripheralDiscovered += dc

EventHandler = getattr(System, 'EventHandler`1')
iuc = EventHandler[EventArgs](systemInformationUpdated_callback)
central.SystemInformationUpdated += iuc
```

It didn't work either (as I believe the bug was corrected in PythonNET 2.2).

Using the console I get

```
dc
<0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]>
iuc
<0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]>
```

The `iuc` object Target property is

```
Target  <__System_EventHandler`1\[\[System_EventArgs\, mscorlib\, Version=4_0_0_0\, Culture=neutral\, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\]\]Dispatcher>    __System_EventHandler`1\[\[System_EventArgs\, mscorlib\, Version=4_0_0_0\, Culture=neutral\, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\]\]Dispatcher
```

I also looked at

- [Python for .NET readme:Using Generics](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#generics),
- [Unable to use Generics in CPython with Python.NET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/157),
- [How can I get generics to work in Python.NET with CPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494331/how-can-i-get-generics-to-work-in-python-net-with-cpython)

Environment:

- Python 3.6 64 bits,
- PythonNET 2.3.0
- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, and was hoping to learn something from your code above, but you only provided fragments. Perhaps you can update this question on what you actually put into the console, or expand a little on your answer below?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't worked on this in a long time. I gave up on PythonNET and switched to IronPython. I think the links I listed in my question are a pretty good start if you want to know more about C# delegation and Python.

Answer (score 2):

With further testing, I realized that the callback is being called, sorry to cry wolf. My callback is as follows:

```
def systemInformationUpdated_callback(sender, e):
    global central
    pdict = dict(central.SystemInformation)
    print "System Information:"
    for key, value in pdict.iteritems():
        print "    "+key+" = "+value
```

`central.SystemInformation` is a `IDictionary<string, string>`. The problem is that PythonNET will not create a dictionary directly from it, the culprit being this line

`pdict = dict(central.SystemInformation)`

But this blows up **silently**, no exception is thrown and the `System Information:` string is never printed. So I thought that the callback was never being called.

As a note, this code runs fine with IronPython.

Thanks!!